# C - trying to assign return value from a function to a variable causes segmentation fault

Tags: c, redis

I will try to post only the important parts because the whole program has 1000+ lines. It normally never crashes, runs fine for days. Today I have been trying to implement some Redis functions to communicate to the program that it needs to fetch new data from a MySQL database.

```
int RedisCheckIfUpdate(redisContext *redis_c) {
    redisReply *redis_reply;
    redis_reply = redisCommand(redis_c, "GETSET update_status 0");

    if (redis_reply->type == REDIS_REPLY_STRING) {
        if (strcmp(redis_reply->str, "newsticker") == 0) {
            freeReplyObject(redis_reply);
            return 1;
        } else if (strcmp(redis_reply->str, "slides") == 0) {
            freeReplyObject(redis_reply);
            return 2;
        }
    }

    freeReplyObject(redis_reply);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int redis_update_status;

    redisContext *redis_c;
    redis_c = redisConnect((char*)"127.0.0.1", 6379);

    if (redis_c->err) {
        printf("Connection error: %s\n", redis_c->errstr);
        redisFree(redis_c);
        exit(1);
    }

    while (1) {
        redis_update_status = RedisCheckIfUpdate(redis_c); // THIS SINGLE LINE CAUSES INSTANT SEGFAULT!
        RedisCheckIfUpdate(redis_c); // THIS WORKS 

        if (RedisCheckIfUpdate(redis_c) == 1) {
            MYSQLNewsticker(con, &nt);
        } else if (RedisCheckIfUpdate(redis_c) == 2) {
            MYSQLSlides(con, &pl);
        }             
    }
}
```

This line...

```
redis_update_status = RedisCheckIfUpdate(redis_c);
```

...causes the program to crash instantly at first loop iteration. As soon as I comment it out, it never crashes and keeps running even though the very same function is being called - just without the return value being assigned to anything.

I may have some workarounds to that but I simply don't understand why would this go so wrong? It's not so complex function and all I'm trying to achieve is to assign return value to a variable. Nothing else happens to the variable. If I comment out said line, I even get a warning that redis_update_status is unused during compilation...

EDIT: I have removed everything but "return 0" from the function body and it still crashes!

Comment: Can you check if redis_reply is NULL?

Comment: It's irrelevant I guess, please read the edit I just made.

Comment: If you are asking for help, please follow suggestions. It is *always* relevant to check a pointer returned by a function.

Comment: There are high chance that your error is elsewhere, you seem to have destroyed your stack. A good candidate is your bogus use of a string literal. Already, `"something"` is of type `char[]`, so you shouldn't need to cast. Then modifying a string literal has undefined behavior.

Comment: I didn't want to sound mean, sorry. No, it is not NULL, I have just checked. By the way, it runs fine without return value assignment.

Comment: Which line in `RedisCheckIfUpdate` segfaults?

Comment: @Jens Gustedt Thank you, I have fixed it but still no improvement. Since there is are no more trivial mistakes in the code I posted so far, I guess a lot of debugging awaits me.

Comment: I run the code without any issues. It's definitely something outside the code you presented like mysql initialization... Where is this nt and pl and con?

Comment: @JuniorCompressor Thank you, I just find it very strange that seemingly such a small change in my code makes it go from working to crashing. I will take my time to carefully debug the code and come back with the answer if I ever find out what's the cause.

Comment: Agree you are blowing the stack.  Does your compiler have a stack canary option?

Comment: Does redistConnect succeed? If not, you are dereferencing null pointer. I know that you seem to have a crash elsewhere but...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like some people pointed out in comments, the segmentation fault was caused by something outside of the code I posted:

```
char time_formatted[30], date_formatted[30];

// Redis connect stuff

while (1) {
    // redis_update_status = RedisCheckIfUpdate(); part goes here
    (...)

    // BEGIN header
    TextMid(1760, 970, time_formatted, SegoeUISB, 60);
    RGBA(41, 39, 39, 1, temp_fill_color);
    vgSetParameterfv(temp_fill, VG_PAINT_COLOR, 4, temp_fill_color);
    vgSetPaint(temp_fill, VG_FILL_PATH);
    WTextMid(1760, 935, date_formatted, SegoeUI, 19);
    // END header

    (...)

    // BEGIN update datetime values
    time(&rawtime);
    timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);
    strftime(time_formatted, 30, "%H:%M", timeinfo);
    wcsftime(date_formatted, 30, L"%A, %d.%m.%Y", timeinfo);
    // END update datetime values
}
```

So as you can see, I was trying to draw clock and date text from string variables which at the time of first iteration weren't set to anything. Once I moved the *update datetime values* part at the start of the loop, I was able to run my entire program properly, including the Redis part.

It was a very stupid mistake which I must have made very early in the process of coding the program and it was left there unnoticed for weeks. The only mind-boggling thing for me is, why didn't it crash for all those weeks up until now, when I added a simple Redis function, completely unrelated to the crashing part...